# IntelliJ Idea not responding for font size change

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Did anyone have the problem when you can change the font size in Editor->Font size but it does not change anything? 
I can set even 50 but it does not make any effect. I was trying to restart etc but it does not help.

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA and Java versions do you use? Did you create a copy of the default scheme that you can modify? Any errors in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Does it happen with all fonts?

Comment: EAP 2017.2, Java 8:131
It happens only with custom color schemes I found.

Comment: Could be caused by a custom scheme. Try the release version.

Comment: Please check `Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Color Scheme Font`, "Use color scheme font instead of the default" - is it enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Font size is also part of Editor display, as well as in 'color scheme' within font it displays the size. But does not work for me either IntelliJ COMMUNITY EDITION 2018 Settings -> Editor -> Font
changed both color scheme font zise and editor font but stays at a small (assume it is default) font approx .11 or.12pt font.

Appears to only change the font size in the Project pane not the Editor's code pane?